# Hyperlink control (inside TemplateField tags) is not acting like an anchor tag?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have this murkup somewhere in my gridview. The gridview is showing the data for that column, but it's not showing up like an anchor tag, i.e. no underlining and not possible to click it (Just like plain-tex).

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" Visible="True">                      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HyperLink ID="statusHpLink" runat="server"  Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>' />                            </ItemTemplate>
         <ItemStyle CssClass="itemstyle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You need to set the NavigateUrl property as it currently does not link anywhere

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to set the NavigateUrl attribute in your markup.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="link" Text="Click Me"
    NavigateUrl="http://stackoverflow.com"/>
```